# How to preserve newlines in GMail mails when posting them via ifttt on Facebook wall?

Tags: gmail, if-this-then-that

I'm trying to post specific emails I get directly on a Facebook wall via [ifttt](http://ifttt.com) (if-this-then-that). The problem is, my newlines (or carriage returns) get destroyed or deleted.
The text in the email looks like this:

> "bla bla bla.
>
> Second sentence bla bla
>
> Yeah the third one bla bla.."

But the final Post on Facebook is like this:

> "bla bla bla.Second sentence bla blaYeah the third one bla bla.."

So every newline is gone.

Any ideas?

Comment: They might grab it as a simple text without any formatting. Have no idea what you can do....dumb solution: count the number of spaces to have the new sentence from the new line probably :)

Comment: (are you / have you) tried sending the email as `plain text`, rather then `html`

Answer (score 1):

It's upto ifttt how they preprocess the string before posting on facebook. You can not do anything about it. Emails are often html formatted and Facebook doesn't support html, so it can be presumed that they are stripping the email off special characters.